# problem with rows.count of a table in a word file

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I opened a Word Doc,which had  tables in it, use VBA from access. I want to add a new line and write something in that line. I worte some code but that code worked only in debug mode. As soon as i clear all break point and let the programm run, i will have a problem. It seems that word will only write data into the first line. Please help。

```
 for j = 0 to 5

   oDoc.tables(1).rows.Add 
   for k=0 to 5
   oDoc.tables(1).cell(oDoc.tables(1).rows.count,k+1)=myarray(k)
   next k

   do something to myarray 
next j
```

Comment: As someone who programs in Access all the time, but is basically unfamiliar with the Word object model, my usual approach to automating Word is to use the macro recorder to figure out how to code something I want to automate. That is, set up your Word document, turn on the macro recorder, and do the actions you want to perform via automation. Stop the recorder and then examine the code. That will likely reveal what you need to do.

Comment: Have you heard about comments in your code ? And about using With oDoc.tables(1) ? You should also show use how you DIMed your array

Answer (score 0):

This is a little strange - I think the code will only work if your myarray() is an array of Range objects, which seems a bit weird. If I make a 3x1 table in my current document and run the following code:

```
Sub x()
For j = 1 To 5
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Add
    For k = 0 To 2
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count, k + 1).Range.Text = "hello"
    Next k
Next j
End Sub
```

... then it seems to work fine in both debug and normal runs. This is in Office 2010.

My guess is that you have some strangeness going on with the myarray() - if it's not actually an array of Range objects, then try explicitly setting .Range.Text as I did in my code and I bet it'll be happier.

Chris